# Linux kernel function 'lookup_page_ext' returning NULL

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am new to Linux kernel programming. I am writing a kernel module for Linux kernel-6.0.
Here is the snippet of my kernel module

```
static int count_wired_pages(unsigned long start_pfn, unsigned long end_pfn)
{
    unsigned long pfn;
    int nr_pages=0, page_mt, count = 0;
    struct page *page;
    struct page_ext *page_ext;
    struct page_owner *page_owner;

    for (pfn = start_pfn; pfn < end_pfn; pfn++) {
        if (!pfn_valid(pfn))
            continue;
        
        /*some code*/

        page = pfn_to_page(pfn);
        if (PageBuddy(page)) {
            pfn += (1UL << page_order(page)) - 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (PageReserved(page)){
            continue;
        }

        page_ext = lookup_page_ext(page);
                if (unlikely(!page_ext))
            continue;

                if (!test_bit(PAGE_EXT_OWNER_ALLOCATED, &page_ext->flags))
                        continue;

                page_owner = get_page_owner(page_ext);
                page_mt = gfp_migratetype(page_owner->gfp_mask);
        nr_pages = (1UL << page_owner->order);
        
        /*some code*/

}
```

In the above code, I am calling the function **lookup_page_ext**. The function is returning NULL.

In the kernel .config file, I have enabled **CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION** and **CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER**. Also, I have added **EXPORT_SYMBOL** to function lookup_page_ext so that it is visible to my module. Is there something that I am missing?